# AngularJS - filter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a problem with filters. I have such files: PostController.js, PostService.js, PostFilers.js - my filter, app.js - routing. Basicly it's a simple blog app and I have an object(returned by 'postService' with blog posts which looks like this:

```
var posts = [
    { id: 1, date: '21-12-2014 14:51', title: 'Blog post article title', content: 'Some content', tags: [1, 2, 3, 5], category: 1 },
    { id: 2, date: '15-11-2014 9:14', title: 'Some kind of title', content: 'Another content', tags: [2, 3, 5], category: 1}
];
```

as you can see in tags I have array of tag Id's, but I want to display tag names instead of tag Id's so I decided to create a filter:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleBlog');
    app.filter("tagName", function () {
        return function (input) {
            return input + "_test";
        };
    });
});
```

Which should return something like 1_test, 2_test etc.
I tried using it like this:

```
{{ tag | filter: tagName }}
```

and

```
{{ tag | tagName }}
```

But the problem here is that this filter does not work. I don't see any error, and I don't see my Id with "test" string.

Content of my controller looks like this:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleBlog');
    app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$location', '$routeParams', 'postService',
    function ($scope, $location, $routeParams, postsService) {
// something here
    });
});
```

HTML of view:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h2>{{ post.id }} - {{ post.title }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ post.date }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <p>Tags: 
        <span ng-repeat="tag in post.tags">
            {{ tag | filter: tagName }}
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
```

Do I have to inject something somewhere? Hope someone could help. Thanks in advance. :-)

PostService.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleBlog');
    app.service('postService', function () {
        var posts = [
            { id: 1, date: '21-12-2014 14:51', title: 'Blog post article title', content: 'Some content', tags: [1, 2, 3, 5], category: 1 },
            { id: 2, date: '15-11-2014 9:14', title: 'Some kind of title', content: 'Another content', tags: [2, 3, 5], category: 1 }
        ];

        return {
            getPosts: function () {
                return posts;
            }
        };
    });
})();
```

PostController.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleBlog');
    app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$location', 'postService',
        function ($scope, $location, postsService) {
            $scope.posts = postsService.getPosts();
        }
    ]);
})();
```

PostFilters.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleBlog');
    app.filter("tagName", function () {
        return function (input) {
            var result = input + "test";
            return result;
        };
    });
})();
```

**Problem solved**
To prevent from polluting global scope by variable **app** I enclosed module definition inside IIFE but I forgot about **brackets** at the end. So code wasn't invoked therefore filter wasn't registered.

Was:

```js
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleBlog');
});
```

Should be:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleBlog');
})();
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your view to this question? Fiddle/bin would be great too.

Comment: Please try this angular.module('SimpleBlog',['filter']);

Comment: @raina77ow added
ShariqueAnsari In what file? Couse I tried in PostFilters.js and It didn't helped.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5wtwgko0/). So it seems like there's indeed a problem with injecting the filter (it's not recognized by the app, hence no action).

Comment: @raina77ow here is fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/kug0q35j/6/ but I can't get it to work...

Comment: @Tomasz Check [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/wndbynq1/). You shouldn't assign `ng-controller` onto the same element as `ng-repeat`.

Comment: @raina77ow I can't couse I need to have them in separate files. That is the problem. Problem is injection not that this does not work, couse syntax is correct.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u7xdw64e/) shows that you can easily separate your modules by files.

Comment: @raina77ow Well.. it does work when I put it inside one file, I mean filter and controller, but when I separate controller to one file and filer to another it does not work.

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem. With `.module(name, deps)`, you _redefine_ the module each time. Instead you should define it just once, then use `.module(name)` form to get it from the modules registry.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
 <html>
<head>
   <title>Angular JS Views</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>



</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="SimpleBlog" ng-controller="PostController">
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">
    <h2>{{ post.id }} - {{ post.title }}</h2>
    <h3>{{ post.date }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <p>Tags: 
        <span ng-repeat="tag in post.tags">
            {{ tag | tagName }}
        </span>
    </p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
angular.module('SimpleBlog', ['filters','services','controllers']);
</script>
<script src="http://abcd.com/postService.js"></script>
<script src="http://abcd.com/PostController.js"></script>
<script src="http://abcd.com/filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

PostControl.js

```
angular.module('controllers',['filters','services']).controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$location', 'postService',
    function ($scope, $location, postsService) {
        $scope.posts = postsService.getPosts();
        console.log($scope.posts);
    }
]);
```

postservice.js

```
angular.module('services',['filters','controllers']).service('postService', function () {
    var posts = [
        { id: 1, date: '21-12-2014 14:51', title: 'Blog post article title', content: 'Some content', tags: [1, 2, 3, 5], category: 1 },
        { id: 2, date: '15-11-2014 9:14', title: 'Some kind of title', content: 'Another content', tags: [2, 3, 5], category: 1 }
        ];

    return {
        getPosts: function () {
            return posts;
        }
    };
});
```

filter.js

```
angular.module('filters',['services','controllers']).filter("tagName", function () {
    return function (input) {
        var result = input + "test";

        return result;
    };
});
```

Comment: It does work in one file, but when I separate controller from filter it does not work anymore...

Comment: can you paste that script which you are writing in separate files?

Comment: I have modified my answers, please try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define filter function inside $scope and then pass it to filter
like filter:myFunction

Comment: Lets I explain you how it works.When you define function like 

var myFunction = function(singleItem){...}
and when you pass it to filter like ...| filter:myFunction the cycle passes to the function each iteration object.the "singleItem" is the object of each iteration

Answer (score -1):

Try Changing this, No need for `filter` keyword  for customer filter

From :

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in post.tags">
           {{ tag | filter: tagName }}
</span>
```

To :

```
<span ng-repeat="tag in post.tags">
           {{ tag | tagName }}
</span>
```

Comment: Yet.. when I remove "filter: " I have an error like this: 
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tagNameFilterProvider <- tagNameFilter

Comment: Here is fiddle for what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/kug0q35j/11/ but I can't get it to work. Take in consideration that I need to have all of this in separate files.

Comment: In one file yes, but the problem is that it does not work in separate files. Something with injecting filter into controller.

Comment: include the files in the order  angularjs ,  module, controller service. Edit your question and  post the full html and js

Comment: Still getting -> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tagNameFilterProvider <- tagNameFilter